# SQL Server 2005 system stored procedure to find out the list of tables affected

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any system defined sp is available in SQL Server 2005, to find what are the tables are got affected when the applicaion is running and we are navigating from one page to other.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no easy way (if any at all) to find that out, unfortunately.

As SQL Server MVP Aaron Bertrand puts it in his excellent blog post [When was my database / table last accessed?](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed) :

*A frequently asked question that surfaced again today is, "how do I see when my data has been accessed last?"  **SQL Server does not track this information for you**.  SELECT triggers still do not exist.  Third party tools are expensive and can incur unexpected overhead.  And people continue to be reluctant or unable to constrain table access via stored procedures, which could otherwise perform simple logging.  Even in cases where all table access is via stored procedures, it can be quite cumbersome to modify all the stored procedures to perform logging.*

However, with the help of the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` DMV (dynamic management views) function and some clever T-SQL programming by Aaron, you *can* find out a few of those answers - check out his very enlightening blog post for details !

However: since this information is based on a DMV and the "D" in DMV stands for **dynamic**, those values are only valid *since the last server reboot* and will be wiped out and **not preserved** when you next have to restart your SQL Server process / reboot your server machine.

Answer (score 0):

I know of none, but Profiler offers a solution. Run Profiler (can be a developer box) and navigate. It will create an output file for you of what is being run.

There are also code tools that show dependencies. I would imagine at least one shows dependencies on SQL objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can run the SQL-profiler to see which commands are fired against the SQL server but you will have to parse them yourself.

You could also try to empty the query cache and then look at it when your navigation is done, but this cache will be contaminated by other queries running on the server (including the ones run by SQL server itself).